# How many cURL types we have?

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am new to curl , i am programming in php , i learned to work with curl codes like this :

```
<?php
$content = 'PHP cURL';
$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com/submit/get.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'var='.$content);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I want to use an API that it needs curl commands but in api documents was some curl codes like these :

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/api/mail.send.json -d api_user=headortail -d api_key=XXXXXXXX
```

I am confused and i don't know what type of curl is it . Can i use in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [**libcurl**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is the C library.
- [**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/) is a command line tool for transferring data using URL syntax that uses **libcurl**.
- PHP has [his own binding](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) of libcurl library.

In your examples, the API you want consume, has examples using cURL command line tool.

cURL have many options to configure the request and in the same way, you have to configure the request using PHP.

In the example provided we've:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/api/mail.send.json -d api_user=headortail -d api_key=XXXXXXXX
```

The equivalent code in PHP would be:

```
<?php
       $params = array(
           'api_user' => 'headortail',
           'api_key'  => 'XXXXXXXX'
       );
       $curl = curl_init('https://example.com/api/mail.send.json');
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
?>
```

The options for the cURL tool you'll find in [cURL man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).
Then, using the [**curl_setopt**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function in PHP, you should configure the equivalent options in your script:

In command line the [**-d**](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) argument set the HTTP POST data, then, in PHP you need use the *CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS* option(you'll find it in curl_setopt documentation) in **curl_setopt** function:

`curl_setopt($curlResource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, <array | string>);`

Answer (score -1):

`cURL` is a C library for making HTTP requests.

Your first example uses PHP bindings do you can access it from PHP.

Your second example uses the command line application.

[`man curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) will give you documentation that explains the command line switches. You can use it to translate the command line version into PHP commands using the bindings you use in the first example.

Comment: Can i use command line in php?

Comment: You can shell out with `system`, but it is an inefficient and hard to debug approach to the problem. You shouldn't do it when you have PHP bindings to the library you want to use.

Comment: You mean it is better to bind. yea?

Comment: It's better to use the PHP bindings to the library then it is to open a shell and call the command line client which has its own bindings to the same library. Writing your own bindings would be silly since there are standard ones already.